# Proof of continuity of a vector function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, vectors

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f(x) = x_i$ where $x_i$ is the $i^{nd}$ component of $x$ regarding the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous in 0.

The definition says :

> Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ and $a \in A$. The function is continuous in a when for all $\epsilon \gt 0$, $\exists \delta \gt 0$ such that for all $x \in A$, $||x - a|| \le \delta$ and $|| f(x) - f(a) || \le \epsilon$.

I know $f(x) = (e_i|x)$.

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have : $|(e_i|x)| \le ||e_i||.||x||$

We have $||x - 0|| = ||x|| \le \delta$.

So $||f(x) - f(0)|| \le ||e_i||.||x|| - 0 = ||e_i||.||x||$

Now, for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ we can take $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{||e_i||}$

So $||f(x) - f(0)|| \le ||e_i||.||x|| \le ||e_i||\delta = ||e_i||\frac{\epsilon}{||e_i||} = \epsilon$.

I wonder if it's correct ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  But this is not a definition of continuity, I'm afraid.  It should go as something like: *is continuous at $a$ when for each $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in A$ such that $\lVert x-a\rVert<\delta$ there holds $\lVert f(x)-f(a)\rVert<\epsilon$*.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the definition. I corrected it.

Comment: Yes, it is O.K.  When you use the standard Euclidean norm, then $\lVert e_i\rVert=1$. But perhaps by $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ you mean any arbitrary norm, then $\lVert e_i\rVert$ need not be $1$. Incidentally, Cauchy-Schwarz *inequality*, not inegality.